# Navigationcontroller toolbar doesn't show UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, swift

I added (or show) a Toolbar on the Navigation Controller with the "Show Toolbar" checkbox in the Attributes Inspector in Xcode 6.2.

Because

> The custom toolbar associated with the navigation controller.
>   (read-only)

I'm using 
`self.navigationController?.setToolbarItems(items, animated: true)` 
to add my items to the toolbar (items is a `NSArray`) but the toolbar doesn't show up any items so far. To test a few things I tried to add a single `UIBarButtomItem` which is created this way:

```
testBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "testTitle", style: .Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

The code is inside the `override func viewDidLoad()` of a `UIViewController`.

I already debugged my code to find out if there is a `nil` around but neither the `UIBarButtonItem` nor the `navigationController` are `nil`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `self.toolbarItems` of the viewcontroller itself. Do not manipulate the toolbar of the navigation controller directly.

(I've not used `self.toolbarItems` in a while so im not 100% positive, but I guess it works like for `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems` and `.rightBarButtonItems`)

EDIT:
Or there should also be a method `setToolbarItems:animated` (on the UIViewController, not the UINavigationController) which is perhaps better.