# UINavigationController's Toolbar isn't displaying items

Tags: swift

I have a custom UINavigationController (`YAKMainNavigationController`) with the toolbar enabled shown at the base of my app's hierarchy. I am attempting to use it as a tab bar to switch between different pages in my app with custom buttons (`YAKFadeButton`). I am using the code below in `YAKMainNavigationController.swift` to add the items to the toolbar:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    addToolbarItems()
}

func addToolbarItems() {
    var items = [UIBarButtonItem]()
    items.append(UIBarButtonItem(customView: YAKFadeButton(normalImage: UIImage(named: "computer"), highlightedImage: UIImage(named: "computer1"), fadeDuration: 0.5, alignment: UIStackView.Alignment.center)))
    items.append(UIBarButtonItem(customView: YAKFadeButton(normalImage: UIImage(named: "bell"), highlightedImage: UIImage(named: "bell1"), fadeDuration: 0.5, alignment: UIStackView.Alignment.center)))
    items.append(UIBarButtonItem(customView: YAKFadeButton(normalImage: UIImage(named: "message"), highlightedImage: UIImage(named: "message1"), fadeDuration: 0.5, alignment: UIStackView.Alignment.center)))
    items.append(UIBarButtonItem(customView: YAKFadeButton(normalImage: UIImage(named: "user"), highlightedImage: UIImage(named: "user1"), fadeDuration: 0.5, alignment: UIStackView.Alignment.center)))

    setToolbarItems(items, animated: false)
    setToolbarHidden(false, animated: false)
    toolbar.tintColor = UIColor.white

    print(items)
    print(toolbarItems as Any)
}
```

The items are not displayed for a reason that I cannot discern. I've captured the UI hierarchy and the items are not even in there, yet the `toolbarItems` array does contain the items. The console output for the code above is as follows:

```
[<UIBarButtonItem: 0x1028272a0> view=<YAK.YAKFadeButton: 0x102825a20; baseClass = UIControl; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x283059740>>, <UIBarButtonItem: 0x102829370> view=<YAK.YAKFadeButton: 0x1028288f0; baseClass = UIControl; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x28305a060>>, <UIBarButtonItem: 0x10282aba0> view=<YAK.YAKFadeButton: 0x10282a120; baseClass = UIControl; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x28305a860>>, <UIBarButtonItem: 0x10282cc00> view=<YAK.YAKFadeButton: 0x10282c180; baseClass = UIControl; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x28305b060>>]
Optional([<UIBarButtonItem: 0x1028272a0> view=<YAK.YAKFadeButton: 0x102825a20; baseClass = UIControl; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x283059740>>, <UIBarButtonItem: 0x102829370> view=<YAK.YAKFadeButton: 0x1028288f0; baseClass = UIControl; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x28305a060>>, <UIBarButtonItem: 0x10282aba0> view=<YAK.YAKFadeButton: 0x10282a120; baseClass = UIControl; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x28305a860>>, <UIBarButtonItem: 0x10282cc00> view=<YAK.YAKFadeButton: 0x10282c180; baseClass = UIControl; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x28305b060>>])
```

Any help with getting these buttons to show is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The solution here might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29119376/1444152 - set `self.toolbarItems`.